# Date Time formatter gives incorrect date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to implement date sorting. Following is the code I am using for this:

```
NSArray *sorters = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"reviewed_datetime" ascending:NO comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSString *strObj1 = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",obj1];
    NSString *strObj2 = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",obj2];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY | HH:mm a"];
    NSDate *n1 = [formatter dateFromString:strObj1]; NSLog(@"date n1 : %@",n1);
    NSDate *n2 = [formatter dateFromString:strObj2]; NSLog(@"date n2: %@",n2);

    return [n1 compare:n2];
}]];

NSArray *sortedLoc = [locReview sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];
[locReview removeAllObjects];
[locReview addObjectsFromArray:sortedLoc];
```

The issue is that the date I am parsing is like(see above code for variables) :`obj1 =Apr 7, 2014 | 2:45 PM`

The date I get in `n1` is `2013-12-22 07:21:00 +0000`.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Try `@"MMM dd, yyyy '|' hh:mm a"` this format.

Comment: Change YYYY to yyyy and you should be fine. YYYY is used in "week-year" ISO calendar and may differ from calendar year.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov thanks mate, it worked! Please write it as an answer so that I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change YYYY to yyyy and you should be fine. YYYY is used in "week-year" ISO calendar and may differ from calendar year.

Comment: I've encountered this when date formatter was giving me wrong year(all was correct except year). It took me several minutes to notice that format is incorrect. :)